# Access RPi's Web Server Connected to Smartphone Hotspot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, web-server

I built a web server with Flask and I am able to access my website on my LAN. Instead of connecting my Pi to my router, my plan is to connect the Pi to my smartphone's hotspot, for portability.

I don't see a problem in transitioning from my router to my smartphone, but if I'm with my friends and they could access my website, I don't want them to consume my data plan if they start streaming videos or going onto social media while connected to my hotspot. They could simply disconnect from my hotspot, but it seems like an inconvenience and a hassle if they're constantly disconnecting and connecting just to access my website.

Is there an alternative way I could give my friends access to my website without compromising my data plan or make it easier to access my website?

Comment: If you don't want your friends to use your mobile data using your mobile hotspot, then don't give them your smartphone hotspot details

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to carry your Raspberry Pi to your friends so they can connect to your web site. Then there is no need to connect the RasPi to your mobiles hotspot. Just configure an access point on the RasPi so your friends can direct connect to it without compromising your data plan on the mobile phone.